# chave estrangeira entre tabelas com Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Gostaria de ajuda para fazer o relacionamento entra tabelas com node js e Sequelize. Tenho 3 tabelas, uma de Usuário, time e outra do relacionamento das duas. Um Usuário pertence a um time e um time contém vários Usuários. Consegui criar as tabelas, porém criei 3 tabelas, não sei como fazer o relacionamento correto entre as tabelas com o Sequelize.

Aqui estão as tabelas

Usuarios:

```html
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const db = require ('../db/conn')

const Usuario = db.define('Usuario', {
    cpf : {
        type : DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull : false
    },
    nome : {
        type : DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull : false
    },
    sobrenome : {
        type : DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull : false
    },
    dataNascimento : {
        type : DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    },
    sexo : {
        type : DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    tipo : {
        type : DataTypes.STRING,
    }
})
module.exports = Usuario
```

Times:

```html
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const db = require ('../db/conn')

const Time = db.define('Time', {
    nomeTime : {
        type : DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull : false,
    }
})

module.exports = Time
```

Usuario_Time:

```html
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const db = require ('../db/conn')
const Usuario = require('../models/Usuario')
const Time = require('../models/Time')

const Usuario_Time = db.define('Usuario_Time', {
    fk_Usuario_IdUsuario : {
        type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
        foreignKey : true
    },
    fk_Time_IdTime : {
        type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
        foreignKey : true
    }
})

Usuario.hasMany(Time, { foreignKey: 'fk_Time_IdTime' });
Time.belongsTo(Usuario, { foreignKey: 'fk_Usuario_IdUsuario' });


module.exports = Usuario_Time
```

Answer (score 0):

o sequilze cria uma tabela com algumas colunas predefinida que são id, createdAt, updatedAt.
vc tera que criar uma relação com id do usuario e o id do time eu faria uma relação de um pra muitos no qual um time teria varios usuarios e cada usuario teria um time

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const db = require ('../db/conn')

const Usuario = db.define('Usuario', {
idTime: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
},
cpf : {
    type : DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull : false
},
nome : {
    type : DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull : false
},
sobrenome : {
    type : DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull : false
},
dataNascimento : {
    type : DataTypes.DATEONLY,
},
sexo : {
    type : DataTypes.STRING,
},
tipo : {
    type : DataTypes.STRING,
}
})
module.exports = Usuario
```

aqui eu só adicionei um campo a mais na tabela usuario onde diz de qual time é o usuario usando o id do time.